# Creating a second generation managed package version gives no error but doesn't create the version

Tags: salesforcedx, 2gp

When I try to execute either of these two commands:

```bash
sfdx package version create -p 0Ho... --code-coverage --installation-key-bypass -b 2gp
# or
sf package version create -p 0Ho... --code-coverage --installation-key-bypass -b 2gp
```

I get this message...

```
Version create.... done
```

But when I run `sf package version list`, no new versions show up.

I am able to deploy the contents of the package to a scratch org without problems...

```
sf project deploy validate --source-dir force-app  
sf project deploy quick --job-id 0Af7...
```

My sfdx-project.json looks like this...

```json
{
  "namespace": "myNamespace",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "57.0",
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "default": true,
      "path": "force-app",
      "package": "My Package (Internal)",
      "versionName": "Calliope 2023",
      "versionNumber": "1.1.0.NEXT",
      "ancestorVersion": "HIGHEST",
      "versionDescription": "Nice description goes here",
      "postInstallScript": "MyPackagePostInstall",
      "branch": "2gp-internal",
      "definitionFile": "config/project-scratch-def.json"
    },
    {
      "default": false,
      "path": "force-app",
      "package": "My Package (Production)",
      "versionName": "Calliope 2023",
      "versionNumber": "1.2.0.NEXT",
      "ancestorVersion": "HIGHEST",
      "versionDescription": "Nice description goes here",
      "postInstallScript": "MyPackagePostInstall",
      "branch": "2gp"
    }
  ],
  "packageAliases": {
    "My Package (Internal)": "0Ho...",
    "My Package (Production)": "0Ho..."
  }
}
```

```bash
sf version
@salesforce/cli/1.73.0 darwin-arm64 node-v18.16.0
```

If I add `--verbose` to the end of the command, it leaves out "done"...

> Version create....

**UPDATE**: I contacted Salesforce Support and they told me it's a development issue so they couldn't help me.

This is absolutely an environmental issue. On a separate system, I installed @salesforce/cli and cloned my project then setup my connection to the DevHub and was able to generate a package version without any problems.

I tried removing @salesforce/cli and reinstalling but that didn't help. Not sure what in my environment is messed up but I can't seem to clear this issue. I've been using the other system to build the package versions in the meantime.

Comment: what about `sfdx package version list` vs `sf package version list`? The version shows up in your Devhub I assume since you can install.

Comment: Exactly the same output for listing package versions with sfdx and sf and it doesn't include the version I am trying to build. No errors. When I do a deploy validate to my scratch org, all 6 tests pass and it successfully lists all the assets the package.

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: Seems to be environmental.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `@salesforce/plugin-packagin` needed to be installed globally....

```bash
npm install -g @salesforce/plugin-packagin
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyword HIGHEST with either the ancestorId or ancestorVersion attribute in the sfdx-project.json file in packageDirectories.

```
"packageDirectories": [{"path": "util", "package": "Expense Manager - Util", "versionNumber": "4.7.0.NEXT", "ancestorVersion": "HIGHEST"},
```

Please refer following document.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_config_ancestors.htm

Comment: Hi Ashwin. Thanks for the reply but my sfdx.json file (shown above) already is using the HIGHEST keyword for the ancestorVersion.